# Create Disk Snapshot from stopped VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have my VMs running on GCE. I want to create snapshots of few attached disks. To make the process safer I first stop the VM then issue the Create Snapshot command.

The problem is that the Create Snapshot operation just continue indefinitely. It never stops. Do I have to take the snapshot while the VM is running?

Comment: Activity list (https://console.developers.google.com/activities) shows that activity is ended after an hour due to an unknown error. But the operation itself is not ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an issue with creating snapshots of shutdown instances. There is a fix being tested as we speak. For now, you can either delete your instance, making sure the disks are preserved, or start your VM and follow the steps described [here](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/10/persistent-disk-backups-using-snapshots.html) to safely snapshot the disk.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, When will the fix will be moved to production?

Comment: The fix has started rolling out to production. It should be in all zones by next week.